# XML saved timestamp not working with PHP date?

Tags: php, xml

I'm storing timestamps in my xml document, but when trying to use them as comparing to the current timestamp it is not working? I have also tried to get it to work with date() but it won't? What am I doing wrong?

XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<data>
  <game id="83832">
    <opponent>Danielle</opponent>
    <oppid>101</oppid>
    <lastdraw>1</lastdraw>
    <turn>1</turn>
    <image>101b.png</image> 
    <nextdraw>1348156426</nextdraw>
    <infopop>0</infopop>
    <playertilesum>89</playertilesum>
    <oppnation>0</oppnation>
  </game>
  <game id="89939">
    <opponent>Bigscreen</opponent>
    <oppid>107</oppid>
    <lastdraw>3</lastdraw>
    <turn>2</turn>
    <image>107a.png</image>
    <nextdraw>1347913606</nextdraw>
    <infopop>0</infopop>
    <playertilesum>101</playertilesum>
    <oppnation>0</oppnation>
  </game>
</data>
```

And what I try to do is this:

```
$timestamp = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];

$xml=simplexml_load_file('TEST.xml');

foreach ($xml->game as $game) {

    if($game->nextdraw < $timestamp){

         echo '['.$r.'] '.$game->nextdraw.'<br>';

    }
}
```

I only want to show the games which is not older than the timestamp? Am I doing this all wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see anything wrong in your code. I ran it and got:

```
[] 1348156426
[] 1347913606
```

What are you getting?

**UPDATE:** In order to check if the condition is executed correctly, use the following `foreach` loop instead.

```
foreach ($xml->game as $game) 
{

    if($game->nextdraw < $timestamp)
    {

        echo "<br> Game's next draw is ". date('m/d/Y h:i:s A', (int)$game->nextdraw);
        echo "<br> Current time is ". date('m/d/Y h:i:s A', (int)$timestamp);
        echo '<br><br>['.$r.'] '.$game->nextdraw;

    }
```

}

Comment: The same, but not sure that is what i want. Is there anyway I can check the dates in a readable fashion?

Comment: I have updated my answer and added code to test if the condition is rendered correctly. Check the **update** section in my answer..